# Troubleshooting Next.js Auth0 integration: API call without response and TypeError 'secret' is required

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, auth0

I am trying to add Auth0 to my nextjs app and Ive followed along with the quickstart guide [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login). I've added the login anchor  and did not use Link as the guide suggested and when you click on it, it just loads infinitly and never reaches the login page. I get the error `API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/login, this may result in stalled requests.` whenever you hit the login button and `TypeError: "secret" is required` . I have triple checked to make sure the .env.local file is correctly set up. [Here](https://github.com/Burmpf/workout_tracker_frontend) is the link to the whole project front end. Ive been struggling with this for a while now and seen many examples with no clear resolution. Any help would be appreciated!

.env.local file is set up as such:

```
AUTH0_SECRET='very long string of random numbers and letters'

AUTH0_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3001/' (we hate 3000 out here)

AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='https://blahblahblah.us.auth0.com/'
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID='xxxxxx'

AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET='xxxxxxx
```

The [...auth0].js file looks like this:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

console.log('the AUTH0_SECRET env var is set: ', !!process.env.AUTH0_SECRET);

export default handleAuth();
```

and index.js looks like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {


  return (
    <>
 
      <Head>
        <title>Workout Tracker</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
       
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <Link href="/calendar">
          Calendar
        </Link>
        <Link href="/DailyDiary">
          Daily Diary
        </Link>
        <a href="/api/auth/login">
          Login
        </a>

      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```